Homework Help - Using Modulo to Count out Bills and Coins
NOTE: I do NOT want the answer! I am hoping to get guidance on next steps
I am new to python and have a question about a problem I'm working:

Define a function consolidate_change that takes as arguments counts of different US coins (similar to the previous function) and prints out the simplest number of bills and coins needed to make that amount.
For example, when called with arguments of 10 quarters, 9 dimes, 8 nickels, and 7 pennies, the function should print:
Number of dollars: 3
Number of quarters: 3
Number of dimes: 1
Number of nickels: 0
Number of pennies: 2
Total amount: $3.87

You must use your previous value_of_change() method in this calculation to determine the total amount.

Now, this is very beginning intro Python, so although I know that there are extremely efficient ways to do this, I am not at the point in our course to use them.
I believe that I can write a modulo function that provides the remainder and then assign the remainder to the next variable, and continue using a modulo function until I have no more remainders. The roadblock I'm having mentally is how to assign the remainder of a modulo to a new variable. Here's what I have so far, which is very much nothing really at all:
def consolidate_change(value_of_change):
    number_dollars = total_value % 1.00
    number_quarters = number_dollars % .25
    number_dimes = number_quarters % .10
    number_nickles = number_dimes % .05
    number_pennies = number_nickles % 0.1

The value_of_change function referenced above:
def value_of_change(quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies):
    q = .25
    d = .10
    n = .05
    p = .01
    total_value = (quarters * q) + (dimes * d) + (nickels * n) + (pennies * p)
    return round(total_value, 2)

Any thoughts on what to do? I am totally fine with basic directions and then having to write the code myself, but if anyone happens to also have any similar-vein examples so I can visualize the structure of the code, that would be much appreciated also!
I got stuck on how to take a modulo function and assign the remainder of the function to a new variable.

I don't understand what is the problem. In consolidate_change you already assign the remainder of a modulo to a new variable. But I see other problem: you have wrong variables in consolidate_change. You should rather define  def consolidate_change(quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies): and first line should be total_value = value_of_change(quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies)

Hint: divmod

create a list or array of objects which defines the demoniations, including the numerical value, create a functions that takes an amount, and a denomination, and returns an object which has the deonination and the total of that denomination, then loop through the first array using the function and recording a running total, that very rough way i would do it

You have around the right idea. Your code is currently assigning the result of the modulo to a variable just like you say. However, logically you don't want to do that at that spot in the code.
Currently, at each step you take the modulo, which gives the remainder of the division, and assign it to the number of that coin. That doesn't make sense to do to get the number of that coin, since the remainder is the amount that doesn't fit in the coins of that denomination. What you want to do is take the floor division, which is the maximumum number of those coins that does fit in the amount. The modulo is the remaining amount that doesn't. You can do floor division in Python with the // operator, like number = top // bottom. It also works to do number = int(top / bottom) when dealing with positive numbers.
So, for each denomination you do 2 things. First, you find how many coins of the denomination fit into the current money amount, using floor division. Then, you use modulo to update the remaining money amount.
Also, I think your function arguments are not quite right. According to the problem description, consolidate_change should take a list of coin amounts like value_of_change. It should use the value_of_change function first to build up the total value, before breaking it back down into the optimal coin amounts.

Just to be clear, top // bottom and int(top / bottom) work the same in this case, but not for negative numbers. Floor division goes towards negative infinity while int() goes towards zero.

Your current line number_dollars  = total_value % 1.00 hints at a misunderstanding. The modulo operator gives you the remainder, as you wrote, but you don't use it like that here.
Using the example amount: 3.87 % 1.00 -> 0.87
This is not 3, like the amount of dollars you might have expected. Consider how you can use the remainder of 0.87 here.

Looks like some other answers were posted while I was working on this! I'll leave it up, though, hopefully it helps you.
I'll try to explain this through examples to help you understand when to use modulo. So as I'm sure you know, mod gives you the remainder. So, if you have 80 cents and you want to see how many quarters that is, you actually don't want to use mod, you'd just want to divide and take the floor (round down). So, the floor of 80/25 would be 3, which is the correct number of quarters.
Now, where mod comes in is to see how many cents you have left over. 80 mod 25 gives you 5, which then tells you that you have 5 extra cents.
So, how would you implement this? Let's say that you have 97 cents, and you want to break this down into the number of coins it takes to make up that.
Start by defining variables for your numbers of coins, and a variable for the number of cents remaining to divide up.

Floor(97/25) = 3. So, it takes 3 quarters. You can set your quarters value to 3.
97%25 = 22. So, 22 cents pass on to the next stage- set your cents variable to 22.
Next, Floor(22/10) = 2. So, you have 2 dimes

The next steps from here on out should be pretty straightforward. I'll let you figure those out, and I'll let you work out how to generalize this and turn it into code. Hope these pointers help!
